# Having trouble with nil optional using parse

Tags: swift, parsing, option-type

I'm trying to download a file from Parse but I'm getting a fatal error: crash, it seems as if the message variable is nil. I've tried to troubleshoot, and I know there is an easy miss I'm just not seeing. Hoping  the community can help as I am new to swift.

```
class InboxViewController: UITableViewController {

  var messages: [PFObject] = []
  var selectedMessage: PFObject?
  var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        // Do stuff with the user
        print("Current user: \(currentUser!.username)")
     } else {
  }
}

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
query.whereKey("recipientIds", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
          for object in objects! {
             let messages = object["file"] as! PFFile
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("Retreived \(self.messages.count) messages")
    }
  }
}


}
```

The crash breakpoint is at the beginning of the query.
Thank you community, another set of experienced eyes always helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can safely unwrap the objects using if let construct

```
 if let objects  = objects {
   for object in objects 
      let messages = object["file"] as? PFFile
       print(messages) 
       // or you can also safely unwarp here 
       // if let messages = object["file"] as? PFFile {
      // print(message)
      // }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
      print("Retreived \(self.messages.count) messages")
}
}
```